# Azure AAD Principals

Tags: powershell, azure

I've manually created an Azure Active Directory tenant in the Azure Portal.  The portal, however, doesn't present an interface where I can grant permission to other principals to own OR contribute to the AAD.  For instance, adding users OR applications.  Is that intentional?  Or is this permissible via Powershell only.  If so, what Powershell commands enable this programmatically?  Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you want to grant permissions to one principal and let it add users and applications?

Comment: Yes Wayne.  That’s precisely what I’m after

Comment: As I known, we can just add user or application with a user or admin in Azure AD.Although you can use principal to login, you still need a user account in that directory. I'm not very clear why you want to do this.